# Argument `primaryMuscles`: Invalid value provided. Expected StringNullableListFilter, provided (String)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

```
const filteredExercises =  await prisma.exercise.findMany({
         where: {
           force: undefined,
           level: undefined,
           mechanic: undefined,
           equipment: undefined,
           primaryMuscles: [
             "Shoulders"
           ],
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           category: undefined
         }
       })
```

Argument `primaryMuscles`: Invalid value provided. Expected StringNullableListFilter, provided (String).

```
async function getFilteredExercises(req,res){
  const {selectedSkillLevel,selectedForce,selectedMechanic,selectedEquipment,selectedPrimaryMuscle,selectedCategory} = req.body
  const filteredExercises =  await prisma.exercise.findMany({
    where: {
      force:selectedForce,
      level:selectedSkillLevel,
      mechanic:selectedMechanic,
      equipment:selectedEquipment,
      primaryMuscles: selectedPrimaryMuscle,
      category:selectedCategory
    }
    
  })
  res.status(200).json({filteredExercises})
}
```

```
model exercise {
  id               Int           @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name             String        @unique
  force            String?
  level            String
  mechanic         String?
  equipment        String?
  primaryMuscles   String[]
  secondaryMuscles String[]
  instructions     String[]
  category      String
  workoutPlans     WorkoutPlan[]
}
```

Comment: Please add more information to the question and try to follow these guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

When utilising Prisma with the `exercise.findMany` function, it appears that there might be a problem with the `selectedPrimaryMuscle` argument. It appears from the error notice that the value for `selectedPrimaryMuscle` that was entered may not have been in the correct format—a StringNullableListFilter.

This is a change you could think about making:

```
const filteredExercises = await prisma.exercise.findMany({
  where: {
    force: selectedForce,
    level: selectedSkillLevel,
    mechanic: selectedMechanic,
    equipment: selectedEquipment,
    primaryMuscles: { contains: selectedPrimaryMuscle }, // Use contains for matching strings in an array
    category: selectedCategory
  }
});
```

`{ contains: selectedPrimaryMuscle }` is used in this adjustment to match the `selectedPrimaryMuscle` in the `primaryMuscles` array. The `primaryMuscles` array in your Prisma model is intended to include one or more values, and this presupposes that `selectedPrimaryMuscle` is a string. Adapt this to your desired matching standards.

Comment: Didnt work 'contains' is unknown argument.